# Python input based on short circuit

Tags: python, logic

I am familiar with Python short circuits(AND, OR, NOT) but this seems weird to me.

Here it is:

What does the following line of Python code do?

```
day = input("What day do you want [Tuesday]: ") or "Tuesday"
```

I am not exactly sure what it is getting from the user and how it is useful.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, this will set `day` to what the user types, unless the user just hits enter.  In this case, `input` will return the empty string, whose truth value is false, so it will use `"Tuesday"` instead.  You can see this here:

```
>>> "" or "Tuesday"
'Tuesday'
```

If the user input is non-empty, then its truth value will be true and it will be used as the result of the `or` expression:

```
>>> "Monday" or "Tuesday"
'Monday'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the result of the `input()` call is falsey, which in this case would be an empty string, `day` will receive `'Tuesday'` as a default value. If the user enters any characters at all before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `day` will be set to the string they entered.